# Full Array Being Displayed instead of just data in WP_List_Table

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function do_meta_boxes() in C:\wordpress\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\plugins\realtyna\realtyna-plugin.php on line 230

I am using xamp as you can see from error is their anything in xamp i need to set to use this function ?. I am trying to add a simple meta box to display add new form.

Note this is just execrt of a plugin class sorry failed to mention.

```
add_meta_box('persons_form_meta_box', 'Person data', 'custom_table_example_persons_form_meta_box_handler', 'person', 'normal', 'default');

 <div class="wrap">
    <div class="icon32 icon32-posts-post" id="icon-edit"><br></div>


    <form id="form" method="POST">
         <?php /* NOTICE: here we storing id to determine will be item added or updated */ ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $item['id'] ?>"/>

        <div class="metabox-holder" id="poststuff">
            <div id="post-body">
                <div id="post-body-content">
                    <?php /* And here we call our custom meta box */ ?>
                    <?php do_meta_boxes('person', 'normal', $item); ?>
                    <input type="submit" value="<?php _e('Save', 'custom_table_example')?>" id="submit" class="button-primary" name="submit">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Has WordPress even been loaded? Have you included `wp_head()`?

Comment: sorry mevius should have said this is a plugin its part of a class didn want to post it all